# How to restore the original order of xsd:elements in xsd:sequence wrappers when websphere is upgraded?

Tags: wsdl, websphere, element, sequence, xfire

So, there's a project around these parts that's pretty old.  It's using Java 1.4 and XFire to produce code-first web services (I know, I know, best practices...).  Anyways, the heads have recently decided *everyone* needs Websphere 7 now!

Upgrading to Websphere 7 changed the WSDL significantly.  For example, before, if this was the order (probably not valid XML but I think you'll catch my meaning)

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element type="xsd:date" name="blah" />
    <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="blah2" />
</xsd:sequence>
```

The new order is this in places, which breaks the older devices which attempt to use the (functional) service:

```
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="blah2" />
    <xsd:element type="xsd:date" name="blah" />
</xsd:sequence>
```

Now, I've suggested that they take their old WSDLs and use XFire to just use the static (i.e. not code-generated) WSDLs to deploy it for a fix.

But is there some way to get Websphere 7 to *not* automatically change the order?  Is it even Websphere 7's fault (maybe XFire?)

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the order, as it is generated by the server. You can change your java file in Websphere to fit your original wsdl. If I were you I would generate the java files from the original wsdl.